# How to change freemarker date value?

Tags: date, freemarker

I am getting {item.pubDate} from XML and the value is: 
Mon, 02 Mar 2015 14:35:47 +0000

so I did this:

```
<#assign starting_point = item.pubDate?index_of(",")>
<#assign date="${item.pubDate?substring(starting_point + 1)}" />
${date?datetime("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z")?date}<br>
```

and the result is: Mar 2, 2015.

My question is, can we change value from Mar to March and if we can then what is the best way to do it? I could have if/elseif statements in freemarker and assign each three letter months to full month name but it looks not good. Any advice/tips will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mater, `MMM` will parse both `Mar` and `March`. The only important thing is to have at least 3 `M`-s, as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html says:

> If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FreeMarker follows the same datetime formatting rules as Java. Use the `?string` built in for dates. You can do:

```
${date?datetime("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z")?string("MMMM dd, yyyy")}
```

Source: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html#ref_builtin_string_for_date